# Google Map js showing a map in china rather than the actual location

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Basically, I'm just trying to set up my web page google map to show a location I've gotten the coordinates to, but it shows a location in China on my web page, no matter what coordinates I try it's always t he same place.

```js
if($('#map-canvas').length != 0){
  var map;
  function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    scrollwheel: false,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.932884, 83.569633),
     styles: [
       {"stylers": [{ hue: "#000000" },
       { saturation: -100 },
       { lightness: -5 }]},
         {
           "featureType": "road",
           "elementType": "labels",
           "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]
         },
         {
           "featureType": "road",
           "elementType": "geometry",
           "stylers": [{"lightness": 100},
                 {"visibility": "simplified"}]
         }
     ]
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   var image = 'include/images/map-marker.png';
   var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.091617, -77.204273);
   var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 }
```

```css
.map-container{height:400px; position:relative; margin:0; padding:0; }
#map-canvas{height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container">
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
```

I expected it to show these coordinates: 39.0916165, -77.2064619

Instead, I see a map of china, example can be seen here:
http://delcontedesigns.com/yaeger/contact

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. I've done maps before but never ran into this issue.

Comment: Your code is centering the map at `center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.932884, 83.569633)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is centering the map at `center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.932884, 83.569633)`.  Change that to `center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.0916165, -77.2064619)` or call `map.setCenter(myLatLng);` (once you have defined that).

**code snippet:**

```js
if ($('#map-canvas').length != 0) {
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.932884, 83.569633),
      styles: [{
          "stylers": [{
              hue: "#000000"
            },
            {
              saturation: -100
            },
            {
              lightness: -5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "road",
          "elementType": "labels",
          "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
          }]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "road",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [{
              "lightness": 100
            },
            {
              "visibility": "simplified"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var image = 'include/images/map-marker.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.091617, -77.204273);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      // icon: image
    });
    map.setCenter(myLatLng);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

```css
.map-container {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

Comment: wow I don't know how I didn't see that. Thank you. A fresh pair of eyes is the best thing ever :P

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're centering your map on the wrong coordinates. Try the following instead:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.0916165, -77.2064619)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jzp2bLok/1/)**